# Filter dataset based on occurrence

Tags: r

I have some large dataset (more than 500 000 rows) and I want to filter it in R. I just want to retain the most relevant information so I thought that it would be a good idea to just save the rows whose elements have an occurrence greater than some value. For example I have this data:

```
A     B
2     5
4     7
2     8
3     7
2     9
4     2
1     0
```

And I want to retain the rows whose element of the A row has an occurrence greater than 1. In this case the output will be:

```
    A     B
    2     5
    4     7
    2     8
    2     9
    4     2
```

I know how to do it with for loops and rbind but since the dataset I am using is very big the performance is greatly hindered. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using either `data.table`, `dplyr` or `base R` methods.  By using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'A', `if` the nrows are greater than 1, we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(.N>1) .SD, by = A]
```

Or we use `dplyr`.  We group by 'A', `filter` the groups that have nrows greater than 1 (`n() >1`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(A) %>%
   filter(n()>1)
```

Or using `ave` from `base R`, we get a logical index and use that to subset the dataset

```
 df1[with(df1, ave(seq_along(A), A, FUN=length))> 1,]
```

Or without using any groupings, we can use `duplicated` to get the index and subset

```
df1[duplicated(df1$A)|duplicated(df1$A, fromLast=TRUE),]
```